# Typedef Return-Type in Objective-C does not work in Swift

Tags: objective-c, swift, callback, typedef

I want to use a Objective-C class in my Swift project and have imported the files and Xcode created the bridge header file and everything is cool... except:

The Objective-C class defines a callback type for a function

```
typedef void (^SSScanManagerCallback)(BOOL success, NSError *error, NSArray *scannedURLs);
```

And uses the type in the function declaration

```
- (void)scanSync:(SSScanManagerCallback)callback; // Synchronous scan.
```

The class in question is the following: https://github.com/counsyl/scanstream/blob/master/ScanStream/SSScanManager.h#L16

**If I then want to use the class in Swift:**

```
let scanManager = SSScanManager();
scanManager.scanSync({(_ success: Bool, _ error: Error, _ scannedURLs: [Any]) -> Void in
    if !success {
        // ...
    }
});
```

I get the following error:

> Cannot convert value of type '(Bool, Error, [Any]) -> Void' to expected argument type 'SSScanManagerCallback!'

---

*Update*: Even if I try to set the argument type like so:

```
scanManager.scanSync({(_ justATry: SSScanManagerCallback!) -> Void in

});
```

I get the error:

> Cannot convert value of type '(SSScanManagerCallback!) -> Void' to expected argument type 'SSScanManagerCallback!'

But how would I set the type to just 'SSScanManagerCallback!' as requested in the error message?

Comment: Just drop the explicit type annotations – let Swift infer them (i.e `.scanSync {success, error, scannedURLs in ... }`. See for example [Using Obj-C completion block in Swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37356631/using-obj-c-completion-block-in-swift)

Comment: @Hamish Amazing, that worked out great, thanks! Would love to give you the correct answer checkmark ;-)

Comment: Note that you don't need to write a semi-colon at the end of each statement in Swift – I would also recommend you take a look at the various short-hand ways you can write closures (https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH11-ID94)

Comment: Thanks for the tips! I am kind of a fan of the semi-colon at the end, but I can understand that people are happy to be able to get rid of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interestingly, it appears that Swift (tested with 3.0.2) now imports Objective-C block argument types without any nullability annotations as strong optionals (previously they were imported as implicitly unwrapped optionals). I can't seem to find the documentation for this change though.

So in your case, the correct signature is:

```
scanManager.scanSync {(success: Bool, error: Error?, scannedURLs: [Any]?) -> Void in
    // ...
}
```

But never write it like this, always let Swift infer the argument types where it can, it solves these kinds of type-mismatch problems for you.

```
scanManager.scanSync { success, error, scannedURLs in
    // ...
}
```

Now you can <kbd>⌥</kbd> click on the closure arguments and Xcode will tell you the type that Swift infers them to be.